# Python While Loop how to rerun

Tags: python

Im stuck on this python code I dislike loops.
How can I rerun the program if the payment is not >= 20?
It just keeps looping otherwise, it wont rerun if the payment isn't >= 20

```
def make_payment(P):
    while True:
            if payment_amount == -1:
                    exit()
            if payment_amount < 20:
                    print("Retry: Payment should not be less than $20")
            if payment_amount > 1000:
                    print("Retry:Payment exceeds $1000")
            if payment_amount >= 20:
                    print("Sucess")
                    break
print("Welcome,Please make a payment")
amount = input("Please enter payment amount: ")
payment_amount = int(amount)
make_payment(payment_amount)
```

Comment: Your code never creates, let alone updates, any variable called `payment_amount`.

Comment: and `P` isn't used, probably that was supposed to be `payment_amount`?

Comment: I added the main program as well now

Comment: Here's  a hint:  The program isn't organized properly to solve the problem.  Possibly, you want the prompt and input part in the repeating indented block of a  while loop, and you want the test for the while loop to be a function that tests the amount entered and returns true or false.

Comment: *"I dislike loops"* - programming is probably not for you...

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a loop in this function:

```
def make_payment(payment_amount):
    if payment_amount == -1:
        exit()
    if payment_amount < 20:
        print("Retry: Payment should not be less than $20")
    if payment_amount > 1000:
        print("Retry:Payment exceeds $1000")
    if payment_amount >= 20:
        print("Sucess")
```

Maybe what you want is a while before you ask for the payment_amount.
And you want this function to return some value to tell the loop to finish when appropriate.

You can try something like this to make some sense out of the loop:

```
def make_payment(payment_amount):
    if payment_amount < 20:
        print("Retry: Payment should not be less than $20")
    elif payment_amount > 1000:
        print("Retry:Payment exceeds $1000")
    elif payment_amount >= 20:
        print("Sucess")
        return True
    return False

print("Welcome,Please make a payment")
while True:
    amount = input("Please enter payment amount (-1 to exit): ")
    payment_amount = int(amount)
    if payment_amount == -1:
        exit()
    if not make_payment(payment_amount):
        print("Payment was not accepted, please try again")
```

Loops are very important in programming, so try to make friends with them.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a main method, call it `main()`. This will continue to ask for the user input, so long as you make the method call. Also, in the function you wrote, you have multiple if statements with no break or return in the statement, meaning it will go through all of the `if` statements.

Also, you should let the user know that if the `payment_amount` is -1, the program will exit. Otherwise, how would they know to exit the program?

`payment_amount` is not declared within the `make_payment` function, but you make `P` the input, so you check if `P` is a certain number (it is the local variable/input).

```
def make_payment(P):
    if P == -1:
            exit()

    elif P < 20:
            print("Retry: Payment should not be less than $20\n")

    elif P > 1000:
            print("Retry: Payment exceeds $1000\n")

    elif P >= 20:
            print("Success!\n")

def main():
    print("Welcome! Please make a payment. \n")
    while True:
        amount = input("Please enter payment amount (or type -1 to exit): ")
        payment_amount = int(amount)
        make_payment(payment_amount)

main()
```

Comment: @Matthias recursion is when you invoke a function call on itself, no? I'm calling *another* function within `make_payment(P)`

Comment: @Matthias ah, you're right! I hadn't noticed. Ill modify it.